# How can I hide a dijit/form/button?

Tags: dojo

I think it is a common sense that providing a simple way to hide/show and enable/disable a button, but I cannot find any document that describe dojo has done such thing.
Any way, I hope it is my fault that I have missed out something while googling, thanks!

The following coding is what I have tried but they just make the button's text invisible:

```
dojo.style(btnInsert, {'visibility':'hidden'});
dojo.style(btnInsert, {'display':'none'});
```

**UPDATE Question:**

To oborden2:

I have tried your code, the result is same as the above code, here is the captured screen:

[image]

To MiBrock:

I have also tried your code and also get the result that same as the above code:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Form widgets in Dijit are special. For all normal Dijit widgets, the `domNode` (outermost node) of the widget receives the `id` property. However, with form widgets, the `focusNode` (which corresponds to the `<input>` element) receives the ID instead, so that things like `<label for="foo">` work properly. In this case, the outermost node has no ID, and you’re actually just hiding the inner HTML input element.

If you already have reference to the widget:

```js
require([ 'dojo/dom-style' ], function (domStyle) {
    domStyle.set(widget.domNode, 'display', 'none');
});
```

If you only have a reference to the ID of the widget/original DOM node:

```js
require([ 'dojo/dom-style', 'dijit/registry' ], function (domStyle, registry) {
    domStyle.set(registry.byId(nodeId).domNode, 'display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
require(["dojo/dom-style","dojo/domReady!"], function(domStyle){
    domStyle.set(dojo.byId(domNode),'display','none');
});
```

The variable "domNode" stays for the id of the Node that should be influenced. This is the way we make it.

Regards, Miriam

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Toggler module

```
require(["dojo/fx/Toggler"], function(Toggler),{
    // Create a new Toggler with default options
    var toggler = new Toggler({
        node: "btnInsert"
    });

    // Hide the node
    toggler.hide();

    // Show the node
    toggler.show();
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/fx/Toggler.html

I imagine you would want to link this to some event using Dojo's `on` module. Link it up to whatever condition triggers the button's need to be hidden.

Comment: I did some test using Toggler but doesn't really hide the button. It just makes it transparent. You can still click the button by hovering on its previous location and clicking it. I'm interested on how you managed to fix this problem?